# Which multiprocessing method map or apply_async?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have a function:

```
def movingWinStretch(u0,u1):
     # u0,u1 are 1D arrays
     # do a bunch of stuff to u0 and u1 

     return C , epsArray, tSamp
```

When I do this workflow on smaller amounts of data I use a couple of nested for loops to loop through the data matrices and get the inputs `u0,u1`. I then append the output C, epsArray, and tSamp to lists after each call to `movingWinStretch`. That would look something like :

```
cArray =[]
dtArray = []
tArray = []
for i in range(1,seisdata.shape[0]):
    for j in range(seisdata.shape[3]):

        u0 = seisdata[0,-1,:,j]
        u1 = seisdata[i,-1,:,j]
        
        C, dtot, tSamp = movingWinStretch(u0, u1)


    cArray.append(C)
    dtArray.append(dtot)
    tArray.append(tSamp)
```

Now I need to do this on a much larger amount of data and would like to get speed up from the mp package if possible. I've written an iterator:

```
def traceIterator(seisdatarray):
    for i in range(1,seisdatarray.shape[0]):
        for j in range(seisdatarray.shape[3]):
            u0 = seisdatarray[0,-1,:,j] 
            u1 = seisdatarray[i,-1,:,j]
            yield u0, u1
```

that yields the input to my function.

I've used the `multiprocessing` package once or twice and thought I would try something like

```
num_proc = 8
pool = mp.Pool(processes = num_proc)
proc = [pool.apply_async(movingWinStretch,args=(u0, u1)) for u0,u1 in zip(*traceIterator(seisdata))]    
results = [p.get() for p in proc]
```

My issue is how do I do the append step for each call to `movingWinStretch` now? Additionally, I don't think `apply_async` is the correct method to use. Perhaps `map` or `starmap` would be better choices since I have multiple inputs?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can use map or starmap instead of apply_async. apply_async is used when you want to submit a single function call as a background task and get the results later using get(). On the other hand, map and starmap are used when you want to apply a function to a collection of arguments in parallel, and get the results as a list.

To use map or starmap for your problem, you need to modify your movingWinStretch function to take a tuple of inputs instead of two separate arguments. You can then use the starmap method to apply the function to a list of tuples of inputs, like this:

```
inputs = [(u0, u1) for u0, u1 in traceIterator(seisdata)]
results = pool.starmap(movingWinStretch, inputs)
```

This will give you a list of tuples, where each tuple contains the outputs of the movingWinStretch function for a given pair of inputs.

To perform the append step for each call to movingWinStretch, you can modify the movingWinStretch function to return a tuple that includes the index of the input pair, like this:

```
def movingWinStretch(idx, u0, u1):
     # do a bunch of stuff to u0 and u1 
     C, epsArray, tSamp = ...

     return idx, C, epsArray, tSamp
```

You can then modify the loop that processes the results to append the outputs to the appropriate lists using the index:

```
cArray = []
dtArray = []
tArray = []
for idx, C, dtot, tSamp in results:
    cArray.append((idx, C))
    dtArray.append((idx, dtot))
    tArray.append((idx, tSamp))

# sort the lists by the index to restore the original order
cArray.sort()
dtArray.sort()
tArray.sort()

# extract the outputs from the sorted lists
cArray = [C for idx, C in cArray]
dtArray = [dtot for idx, dtot in dtArray]
tArray = [tSamp for idx, tSamp in tArray]
```

Note that sorting the lists by the index is necessary because the order of the outputs in the results list is not guaranteed to be the same as the order of the inputs.

Comment: Great! I will give this a try. I tried to upvote the answer, but I don't have a high enough reputation.

Comment: I don't need to use zip to unpack the multiple inputs from the generator?

Comment: This _"Note that sorting the lists by the index is necessary because the order of the outputs in the results list is not guaranteed to be the same as the order of the inputs."_ is actually not the case. You have to explicitely use something like [`.imap_unordered`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap_unordered) to not get the guarantee  that the results are in the order of the input. This only makes sense in a _lazy_ context, but `.(star)map` blocks until all results are back. (@magmadaddy)

Comment: Additional point: this `inputs = [(u0, u1) for u0, u1 in traceIterator(seisdata)]` is not nessecary since `traceIterator(seisdata)` already is an iterable that produces tuples. You can just plug it into `.starmap` as it is.

Answer (score 0):

`Pool.starmap` reflects the input-order in the output, so there's no need for artificial indices and sorting. You could also let `zip` do the extraction into the 3 output lists, something like the following:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

# Your movingWinStretch
def foo(u0, u1):
    return u0, u1, u0 + u1

# Your traceIterator
def arguments(n, m):
    for u0 in range(n):
        for u1 in range(m):
            yield u0, u1

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    num_proc = 8
    # a, b, c your cArray, dtArray, tArray
    with Pool(num_proc) as pool:
        a, b, c = zip(*pool.starmap(foo, arguments(2, 3)))
    print(f"{a = }, {b = }, {c = }")
```

Result here:

```
a = (0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), b = (0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2), c = (0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3)
```

If you need lists, then do

```py
    ...
        a, b, c = map(list, zip(*pool.starmap(foo, arguments(2, 3))))
```

instead (or use a comprehension if you don't like `map`).